# Software for browsing classes in a C/C++ project

Tags: c++, class, modeling

I have seen that some developers have a graphical representation of all their classes in an image file which comes with their project. How can I myself create these graphics?

Basically they show what classes exist in a file and how these files relate to each other.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doxygen allows you to generate interactive class diagrams. Check out this page: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html how to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

It might be [Doxygen](http://doxygen.org), a software that generates documentation with dependancy graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has the ability to [generate class diagrams](http://www.vogella.de/articles/UML/article.html) and export them as images.

Answer (score 1):

One common tool that allows people to do that fairly easily is [Dot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language), which comes as part of [Graphviz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz). Dot is sort of a markup language describing graphs. You can generate Dot files manually if you like, but there are a lot of code analysis tools that will do the job for you. Doxygen is one.

Answer (score 0):

Another great tool for creating UML class diagrams is [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/).